# Reactor Netty - keepalive

Tags: spring-webflux, netty, keep-alive, reactor-netty

I have an application that uses Webflux and I'm trying to enable `keepalive` on the server.

I did the following:

```
@Component
public class ServerConfiguration
    implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<NettyReactiveWebServerFactory>
{
    private static final int TIMEOUT = 10;

    @Override
    public void customize( NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory )
    {
        factory.addServerCustomizers( httpServer -> httpServer.doOnConnection( connection -> {
            connection.channel().config().setOption( SO_KEEPALIVE, true );
            connection.addHandlerLast( new IdleStateHandler( 0, TIMEOUT, 0 ) );
        } ) );
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the server do send a `keepalive` every 10s but it doesn't seem to be working.

What I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if I'm correct, the Netty IdleStateHandler does not send ping messages, it just triggers an IdleStateEvent when a Channel has not performed read, write, or both operation for a while.

Now, to enable keep alive on the server, did you try to add more channel options like TCP_KEEPIDLE, TCP_KEEPINTVL, or TCP_KEEPCNT ? And you can use HttpServer.childOption, for example:

```
        factory.addServerCustomizers(httpServer ->httpServer
                .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
                .childOption(NioChannelOption.of(ExtendedSocketOptions.TCP_KEEPIDLE), 60)
                .childOption(NioChannelOption.of(ExtendedSocketOptions.TCP_KEEPINTERVAL), 10)
                .childOption(NioChannelOption.of(ExtendedSocketOptions.TCP_KEEPCOUNT), 3)
                );
```

This is for Nio transport, but there are also EpollChannelOption if you are using Epoll transport (check https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/1.1.6/reference/index.html#_tcp_level_configuration_2).

hope this helps.

Comment: Either option doesn't work. I never see any keepalive being sent on wireshark